# Training sets for AdaBoost algorithm

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, training-data, adaboost

How do you find the negative and positive training data sets of Haar features for the AdaBoost algorithm? So say you have a certain type of blob that you want to locate in an image and there are several of them in your entire array - how do you go about training it? I'd appreciate a nontechnical explanation as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

First, AdaBoost does not necessarily have anything to do with Haar features.  AdaBoost is a learning algorithm that combines weak learners to form a strong learner.  Haar features are just a type of data on which an AdaBoost algorithm can learn.

Second, the best way to get them is to prearrange your data.  So, if you want to do facial recognition a la [Viola and Jones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola-Jones_object_detection_framework), you'll want to mark the faces in your images in a mask/overlay image.  When you're training, you select samples from the image, as well as whether the sample you select is positive or negative.  That positivity/negativity comes from your previous marking of the face (or whatever) in the image.

You'll have to make the actual implementation yourself, but you can use [existing projects](http://code.google.com/p/icsiboost/) to either guide you, or you can modify their projects.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm still unclear about how you actually choose the positive/negative training samples. When you mark the type of blob or face or whatever that you want, how do you do that in a way that is automated? I thought AdaBoost is automated program. by the way, sorry I'm adding this as an answer not comment but I don't see a comment option.